# Radius of Convergence for a given sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $$\begin{cases} a_n = 1\ \text{ if } \exists k\in\mathbb{N}\ n=k^2\\ a_n = 0\ \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n$.

What i tried :

$a_n$ is either $0$ or $1$ , thus $\frac{1}{R} = \lim\sup|a_n|^\frac{1}{n}$ where , $R$ is the radius of convergence...
$\sup|a(n)|^\frac{1}{n}$ remains $1$ only... So , $R=1$;
Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct! This is an alternative proof:

Let $b_n=1$ for all $n$ then clearly we have $a_n\le b_n$ and then $R_a\ge R_b=1$. Now for $x=1$ the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n=\sum_{n=0,\; n\;\text{is a square}}^\infty 1$$
is divergent so $R_a\le 1$. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

You have the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$$

Using the ratio test

$$\left|\frac{x^{(n+1)^2}}{x^{n^2}}\right|=\left|x^{2n+1}\right|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\begin{cases}\infty&,\;\;|x|>1\\1&,\;\;|x|=1\\0&,\;\;|x|<1\end{cases}$$